# App Scripts: Attempting to grab a specific form response, get a URL, and email that URL

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to capture a directly link or the response ID to create a link and forward it into a ticketing queue but every function seems to give me the wrong ID.

```
function onFormSubmit()
{

//email content creation
var formID = '(copy/pasted from form url)'; 
var emailBody = "You have received a form submission: ";
var emailAddress = 'TestEmail';
var emailSubject = 'Your form has a new response';

//find the form
var form = FormApp.openById(formID)
var formResponses = form.getResponses();

//find the last response
var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
var responseID = lastResponse.getID();

//build link
var url = https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ + formID + "/edit#response=" + responseID;

//send email
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailBody  + url);

}
```

Hopefully this comes off as coherent on what I'm trying to do.  I've attempted to use the

```
onFormSubmit(e) 
responseID = e.getResponses[e.length-1].getID();
```

but that doesn't work either.

I've found numerous posts on how to do this, but even copy/pasting the test code throws errors of getID being undefined.

If anyone can help figure this out, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please modify `getID()` to `getId()`, and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getId()) But if this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: It is not supported to get the url of individual response.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get a url to edit the form response.   If that's the case, you can use `var url = lastResponse.getEditResponseUrl()`  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl()

Comment: the getEditResponseUrl() one requires a sign-in to access it. It looks like it's to edit the response itself, not to view it as the summary. 
 After a lot of testing with other people, most have concluded it's impossible to do this as idfurw said :(.  Though if anyone can get it working and lead to a specific response, let me know!